# Не удалить OpenOffice

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, open-office

При попытке удалить OpenOffice я получаю следующее:

```
$ sudo apt-get --force-yes remove openoffice*
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Note, selecting 'openoffice-brand-ru' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ru-help' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ogltrans' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-writer' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-debian-menus' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-brand-impress' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-gnome-integration' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-fr-fr' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-thesaurus-de-ch' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-onlineupdate' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-en-ca' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-en-us' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-updatedicts' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ooolinguistic' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openofficeorg-desktop-integration' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ru-res' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-ru' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-kde' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-common' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ure' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-desktop-integration' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-an' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-ca' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-eo' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-es' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-eu' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-fo' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-gl' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-debian-menus' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-nb' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-nn' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-nr' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-ns' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-ss' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-st' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-tl' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-tn' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-uz' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-ve' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-xh' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-zu' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-pyuno' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ru-impress' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-brand-calc' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-impress' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-xsltfilter' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ru' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ru-calc' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-graphicfilter' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ooofonts' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-core01' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-core02' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-core03' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-core04' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-core05' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-core06' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-core07' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-brand-draw' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hunspell' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ru-draw' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-en' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-fi' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-ga' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-hr' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-id' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-calc' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-writer' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-lt' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-pl' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation-ru' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org2-thesaurus' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-brand-math' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-ure' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ru-math' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-writer' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-thesaurus-de' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-calc' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-thesaurus-it' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-thesaurus-pl' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-bundled' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-impress' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-brand-base' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-draw' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ru-base' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-calc' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-brand-writer' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-math' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-dict-en' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-dict-es' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-dict-fr' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-base' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-en-us' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-core' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-unbundled' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-draw' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-dev-doc' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-math' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-dmaths' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-de-at' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-de-ch' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-spellcheck-de-de' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-base' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-images' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-javafilter' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-unbundled' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-hyphenation' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org3-base' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-thesaurus-en-au' for glob 'openoffice*'
Note, selecting 'openoffice-ru-writer' for glob 'openoffice*'
Пакет «openoffice.org-thesaurus-it» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-updatedicts» выбирается «dictionaries-common»
Пакет «openoffice.org-hunspell» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org-core» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-an» выбирается «hunspell-an»
Пакет «openoffice.org» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-ca» выбирается «hunspell-ca»
Пакет «openoffice.org-spellcheck-en-us» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-eu» выбирается «hunspell-eu»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-gl» выбирается «hunspell-gl-es»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-uz» выбирается «hunspell-uz»
Пакет «openoffice.org-writer» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-hyphenation-en-us» выбирается «hyphen-en-us»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-hyphenation-en» выбирается «hyphen-en-us»
Пакет «openoffice.org-hyphenation-hr» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-hyphenation-pl» выбирается «hyphen-pl»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-hyphenation-ru» выбирается «hyphen-ru»
Пакет «openoffice.org-base» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice-unbundled» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org-common» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org-dev-doc» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-eo» выбирается «myspell-eo»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-es» выбирается «myspell-es»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-fo» выбирается «myspell-fo»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-nb» выбирается «myspell-nb»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-nn» выбирается «myspell-nn»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-nr» выбирается «myspell-nr»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-ns» выбирается «myspell-ns»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-ss» выбирается «myspell-ss»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-st» выбирается «myspell-st»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-tn» выбирается «myspell-tn»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-ve» выбирается «myspell-ve»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-xh» выбирается «myspell-xh»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-zu» выбирается «myspell-zu»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-thesaurus-de» выбирается «mythes-de»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-thesaurus-de-ch» выбирается «mythes-de-ch»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-thesaurus-en-au» выбирается «mythes-en-au»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org2-thesaurus» выбирается «mythes-en-au»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-thesaurus-pl» выбирается «mythes-pl»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-hyphenation-en-ca» выбирается «openoffice.org-hyphenation»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-hyphenation-fi» выбирается «openoffice.org-hyphenation»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-hyphenation-ga» выбирается «openoffice.org-hyphenation»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-hyphenation-id» выбирается «openoffice.org-hyphenation»
Пакет «openoffice.org-calc» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org-kde» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-fr-fr» выбирается «myspell-fr-gut»
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice.org-spellcheck-tl» выбирается «myspell-tl»
Пакет «openoffice.org-dmaths» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org-bundled» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-writer» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-dict-es» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-dict-en» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-dict-fr» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-base» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-impress» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-ru» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-math» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-calc» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org3-draw» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org-ure» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Заметьте, вместо «openoffice-desktop-integration» выбирается «openoffice-debian-menus»
Пакет «openofficeorg-desktop-integration» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org-debian-menus» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Пакет «openoffice.org-hyphenation-lt» не установлен, поэтому не может быть удалён
Возможно, для исправления этих ошибок вы захотите воспользоваться «apt-get -f install»:
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libreoffice-core : Зависит: libreoffice-common (> 1:5.1.4) но он не будет установлен
 libreoffice-script-provider-python : Зависит: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) но он не будет установлен
 libreoffice-style-elementary : Зависит: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) но он не будет установлен
 libreoffice-style-galaxy : Зависит: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) но он не будет установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt-get -f install», не указывая имени пакета, (или найдите другое решение).
```

И как мне теперь удалить OpenOffice? В менеджере приложений его нет. Open Office был установлен через `dpkg` из `.deb` файлов

Comment: а звёздочка зачем? `sudo apt-get remove openoffice`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin потому что open office разделён на кучу отдельных пакетов

Comment: Мне обычно `purge` вместо `remove` в таких случаях помогал.

Comment: @Виктор, а ещё пакеты связаны зависимостями. так что там насчёт «без всяких звёздочек»? приведите, пожалуйста, полный вывод команды.

Comment: Можно ещё посмотреть как `aptitude purge openoffice` отработает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каталоге с `.deb` файлами достаточно запустить

```
$ sudo dpkg -P `find -iname '*.deb' -exec dpkg --info '{}' \; | awk '/Package:/ {print $2}'`
```

[Источник](https://askubuntu.com/a/439474/490870)

Comment: откуда у вас в текущем каталоги взялись файлы, имена которых заканчиваются на `.deb`? что это за файлы? зачем вы извлекаете из них имена пакетов? как этот ответ может помочь хоть кому-нибудь ещё?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin он устанавливал из `.deb.` файлов. Если он их не удалил, команда должна отработать, посколько dpkg не обрабатывает зависимости

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge openoffice openoffice-common #Удаляет основу
sudo apt-get autoremove #Удаляет теперь уже не нужные зависимости
```

Comment: Опс, забыл, что тут openoffice, а не libreoffice. Ну ладно - дожно сработать после правки команд :D

Comment: наверно, всё же лучше исправить ответ.